# How to add multiple images to offers-table using joins?

Tags: php, mysql, image, codeigniter, join

I made an upload form to upload multiple images to the server. I also made a function in my model to add the file names to the database, this all works great. I want to assign all the images to one offer (table in my database)

I am using table joins to add more than one offer to a specific company (table in my database)

So 1 company can have more offers, But an offers has to be more than one image.

**Translation: 
Aanbieding means Offer,
Bedrijven means company,
foto means image**

The current case: There are created 3 offers. So for each image there's an offer created, but with the same info, only difference is the image id.

My table for joining the companies, offers and images looks like the following:

```
bedrijfaanbiedingen
-------------------
idbedrijfaanbiedingen
idbedrijven
idaanbiedingen
idfotoaanbiedingen
idaanbiedingcat
```

As you can see it's possible to have 1 company with several offers and several images.

My model for adding an offer looks like this:

```
public function addaanbieding($image_data = array())
{
    $data1 = array(
        'Aanbieding' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingnaam'),
        'Tekst' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingomschrijving'),
        'Prijs' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingprijs'),
        'Conditie' => $this->input->post('aanbiedingconditie'),
        'prijssoort' => $this->input->post('prijsopties'),
    );      
    $this->db->insert('Aanbiedingen', $data1);

    $aanbiedingid = $this->db->insert_id();
    $catid = $this->input->post('categorie');

    if($this->db->affected_rows() >= 1) 
    { 
        $to_bedrijfaanbiedingen['idaanbiedingen'] = $this->db->insert_id();
        $to_bedrijfaanbiedingen['idbedrijven'] = $this->session->userdata('idbedrijven');
        $to_bedrijfaanbiedingen['idaanbiedingcat'] = $catid;
        $insert_data = array(
            'fotonaam' => $image_data['file_name']
        );
        $input = $this->input->post('userfile');
        if(isset($input)){
            $this->db->insert('fotoaanbiedingen', $insert_data);
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
        $fotoid = $this->db->insert_id();

        $to_bedrijfaanbiedingen['idbedrijven'] = $this->session->userdata('idbedrijven');
        $to_bedrijfaanbiedingen['idaanbiedingen'] = $aanbiedingid;
        $to_bedrijfaanbiedingen['idfotoaanbiedingen'] = $fotoid;

        $this->insert_bedrijfaanb2($to_bedrijfaanbiedingen);
    }; 
}

public function insert_bedrijfaanb2($data) 
{ 
    $this->db->insert('bedrijfaanbiedingen', $data); 
    return $this->db->affected_rows() >= 1 ? TRUE : FALSE; 
}
```

I hope it's clear what I want.

**I want 1 offer on 1 company with 2 or more images.**

EDIT:

My whole table structure:

```
bedrijven (companies)
---------
idbedrijven
bedrijfsnaam
profiel
plaats
telefoonnummer
etc...

Aanbiedingen (offers)
------------
idaanbiedingen
Aanbieding
prijs
conditie
etc..

bedrijfaanbiedingen (companyoffers)
-------------------
idbedrijfaanbiedingen
idbedrijven
idaanbiedingen
idfotoaanbiedingen
idaanbiedingcat

fotoaanbiedingen
---------------
idfotoaanbiedingen
file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not entirely clear what you want (sorry) so please forgive me if I am explaining the wrong thing.  What I think you are trying to do is implement a one-to-many relationship in your database.  This is best done with a linking table if the number of images is arbitrary.
The system I describe below will allow you to link an effectively infinite number of images to offers, companies to offers and offers to companies.

I'm not sure how your tables are constructed so I'll make some up:

Company (company_id,company_name) 
Image (image_id,image_url)
Offer (offer_id,offer_details)
Company_offer (company_offer_id,company_id,offer_id)
Image_offer (image_offer_id,image_id,offer_id)

Image_company (image_company_id,image_id,company_id) //optional if you wish images to be linked to companies without also having an offer.

An offer is created.  You link the company to the offer using company_offer and the image to the offer using image_offer.

The sql would be along the lines of:

SELECT company_name,image_url, {others} FROM Company 
LEFT JOIN Company_offer ON Company.company_id=Company_offer.company_id
LEFT JOIN Image_offer ON Company_offer.offer_id=Image_offer.offer_id
LEFT JOIN Image ON Image_offer.image_id = Image.image_id
WHERE {where criteria go here}  //note this sql is untested.

The key to happiness here is database design.  You can implement one-to-many relationships easily if you keep the data stored in each table to a minimum (ideally no non-id data in the table should be duplicated elsewhere)  Look up 4th Normal Form if you want to know more.  It does make for lots of bitty tables and occasionally some gnarly joins but the outcome is usually a much easier system to navigate with lower storage costs.

Comment: What if I add my table structure and you add codeblocks to your answer and edit the tables to mine? that way it's a bit more clear. I will add my table structure now.